# Different results from Command Line and Script

Tags: powershell, access-denied, cmdlets

If I run `Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb` I get back a list of all web sites including Central Administration. If I put this line in a script and run this script I get the following error message (both in 'normal' and in elevated mode):

```
PS C:\[...]> . allwebs.ps1
Get-SPWeb : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At C:\[...]\allwebs.ps1:1 char:76
+ Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletGetWeb:SPCmdletGetWeb) [Get-SPWeb], Unauthorize
   dAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetWeb
```

The account is in the farm administrators group, is sitecollection administrator and has full controll within all webs.

What is the difference between running the Cmdlets from command line and within a script?

Comment: when running the script in powershell are you opening it up as admin?

Comment: As I've already mentioned: The issue occurs when I run the script as a 'normal' user, as well as when I run it as an admin (elevated mode).

Answer (score 1):

make sure that the file allwebs.ps1 has the correct permissions! goto the file, right click and select properties. Now click on security tab and then edit button. Make sure the correct accounts are there like the admin account.

Could you also show some of the powershell code? I presume that your opening up sharepoint 2010 shell managment and dragging droping the file and then hit enter?